# Как правильно обработать данные с инпута в тильде и вывести их?

Tags: javascript, tilda

Необходимо сделать несложный расчет после ввода данных!
Стандартными средствами тильды такого не получиться, так как формула (процент зависит от введённого значения).
По факту необходимо считать значение с поля ввода, и после некоторых вычислений вывести в этом же блоке полученный результат.

Вот [пример](https://codepen.io/fractal-web/pen/GRvpKjd) без оформления (все прекрасно работает).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#rec123456789 form').submit(function (e) 
{
  var smeta = $('#rec123456789 input[type="text"]').val();
  var price = 24000;
  if (smeta<1000000) {
    price = (smeta/100)*1;
  } else if ((smeta>10000000) && (smeta<30000000)) {
    price = (smeta/100)*1.35;  
  } else if ((smeta>30000000) && (smeta<100000000)) {
    price = (smeta/100)*1.23;
  } else if ((smeta>100000000) && (smeta<200000000)) {
    price = (smeta/100)*1.10;
  } else if ((smeta>200000000) && (smeta<500000000)) {
    price = (smeta/100)*1.09;
  } else {
    price = (smeta/100)*1.08;
  }
  if (price<24000) {
    price = 24000;
  }
  $("#rec123456789 b:contains('24000')").html(price.toFixed(2));
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

});

Данный код, соответственно, с изменением ID блока вставляю произвольным скриптом в тильду сразу после блока в котором необходимо провести расчеты, но в тильде данный код не срабатывает!

Подскажите каким образом это правильно реализовать!?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо смотреть на html разметку, которую делает тильда.

Comment: ну там тоже формой, через консоль селектор $('#rec123456789 form') - проходит нормально показывает необходимый мне элемент. Но судя по всему мой скрипт не перебивает стандартное поведение в тильде и данные отправляются с формы! тот самый "e.preventDefault();" не срабатывает - незнаю почему!

Comment: может, потому что там сабмит формы происходит вручную, при нажатии на кнопку. И может, сабмита формы вообще нет - может там ajax запрос. Вы уверены, что именно сабмит формы происходит?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko А вот это уже интересное замечание, попробую просто по клику, а не по сабмиту обработать!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря комментарию [@Stepan Kasyanenko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1339438/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%85/1340445#comment2371235_1339438), сделал по событию клика на кнопку и все сработало.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте тот комментарий, который Вам помог, в ответ